# Data Loss Prevention Policy in Powerautomate

Tags: power-automate

Does splitting or manipulating a pdf file in power automate break the data loss preventing policy regardless if it is a wanted action?

Answer (score 1):

Data Loss Prevention policies in Power Automate do only two things:

- Provides the list of either allowed or blocked connectors
- Prevents the communication between business and non-business connectors

You can read more about [connector classification in the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-platform/admin/wp-data-loss-prevention#connector-classification) - it should give you an overview of how the mechanism works.

To find out whether the action is allowed *in your organization* you can do the following:

1. Create a flow
2. Add the connector/action you'd like to check into your flow
3. Check if you can save it.
4. If you receive error saying that the action violates your org's DLP policy, you will know it's not allowed:
   [image: Error saying that action violates DLP policy]

> **NOTE**: The solution above doesn't take into account internal rules set in your organization. If you have any doubts, ask your admin.

Comment: Hi @Robert , in this case since we don't have the DLP at place, ideally whom to connect , is it the M365 Admin in the organization ?

Comment: @Neeraj, yes, M365 Admin should be able to check who has rights to add/manage DLP policies